# A ring $R$ has maximal ideals ... choose the correct option?

Tags: abstract-algebra

A ring $R$  has  maximal ideals.

Choose the correct options:

a) if $R$ is finite

b)  if  $R$ is infinite

c) if $R$ is finite with at least 2 element

d) only if $R$  is finite

My attempts: I know that $I$ is a maximal ideal of a ring $R$ if there are no other ideals contained between $I$ and $R$.

Here I'm confused about the options.

Comment: Do your ring have an identity?

Comment: Would you mind improving the formatting a bit? This too reflects the effort you put on the question. Also, what have you tried besides reading the definition of maximal ideal?

Comment: I think in this question, rings are not necessarily equipped with multiplicative identity.

Comment: Every finite field is a ring with one single maximal ideal, so (a) is correct. For any field $\;F\;,\;\;F[x]\;$ is a ring with lots of maximal ideals, so choosing an infinite field (b) is correct...

Comment: If nonunital rings are considered, then only (c) is correct.

Comment: @DonAntonio The question says “ring”, not “field”

Comment: @egreg You're aware of the fact that fields are ring, right?

Comment: @DonAntonio Your comment is rude. I'm perfectly aware there are rings which are not fields. You are instead still apparently unaware of your logical fallacy. It's like saying that birds are black because crows are birds and are black.

Comment: @egreg I think it is your logic which fails badly: if the OP asks about *rings * then **anything** that is a ring serves...right or wrong? There we go. Thus, either the OP accepts the examples, or else (s)he writes specifically that the wanted examples must be rings that are not fields. But it really doesn't matter. Have it your way.

Comment: @DonAntonio “If a ring $R$ is finite, then $R$ has maximal ideals”. Do you think it's a true statement?

Comment: @egreg Of course not. The zero ring is an example. That is trivial, of course. What that has to do with anything, though.

Comment: @DonAntonio OK, you are reading a different question. Look at the position of “if”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to find a ring with no maximal ideals: $\{0\}$.

There are infinite abelian groups with no maximal subgroup; find one and endow it with the trivial multiplication $ab=0$ for all $a$ and $b$.

On the other hand, $\mathbb{Z}$ is an infinite ring; does it have maximal ideals?

If $R$ is finite with at least two elements, then the set of proper ideals is finite and not empty, so…

Comment: Why is the set of proper ideals of a finite ring with more than two elements non empty? Isn't $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with $p > 2$ a counterexample?

Comment: @GuidoA. $0$ can be a maximal ideal.

Comment: @Batominovski I see, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: thanks u @egreg . Yes  $\mathbb{Z}$ has  maximal ideals   ,as  maximal ideals  are of the form <p>, where p is prime.

Comment: @stupid That's right.